# Handling mouse event in javafx: how to add listener?

Tags: event-handling, javafx-2, actionlistener

I have a problem with the event handler, this is the code. There is a compile error. NetBeans says: cannot find symbol, method `setOnAction`. 
This is exactly like the example I found at [Oracle Doxs](http://docs.oracle.com).

And then I have another question: how should i use this listener? by creating an object in main?

```
public class StartButtonController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private Button startButton;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StartButtonController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        startButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                startButton.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                startButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

import `javafx.scene.control.Button`.
and
remove the line `import java.awt.Button;`

Comment: @BenyaminNoori. Same exception or different. Post full stacktrace.